# oracle Stored Procedure with Out parameter

Tags: c#, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm having trouble using an Oracle stored procedure that has an out parameter.  I don't have access to view the actual stored proc but here is the method signature:

```
CHECKPASSWORDUSED (System.Decimal USER_IN, System.String PASSWORD_IN, out System.Decimal PW_FAIL)
```

And this is how I'm trying to call it.

```
public decimal CheckIfPasswordUsed(long userId, string password)
{
    decimal? used;
    _context.CHECKPASSWORDUSED(userId, password, out used);
    return Convert.ToDecimal(used);
}
```

I had to define an out variable but I'm not sure if I'm using this right.  Am I on the right track?

Edit:  The error messages I get are:

> [OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
>   PLS-00201: identifier 'CHECK_PASSWORD_USED' must be declared
>   ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
>   PL/SQL: Statement ignored]
>      Devart.Data.Oracle.bc.d() +872
>      Devart.Data.Oracle.an.i() +112
>      Devart.Data.Oracle.an.c() +3016
>      Devart.Data.Oracle.x.a(Int32 A_0, bt A_1) +3343
>      Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior behavior, IDisposable disposable, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, Boolean nonQuery) +4880
>      Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery) +764
>      Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +69
>      Devart.Data.Linq.Provider.DataProvider.ExecuteQuery(CompiledQuery compiledQuery, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, Object lastResult) +3675

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, I'm not getting a similar error.  Am I calling the stored procedure correctly?  I can't find any documentation similar to my usage.

Comment: Please put the complete error stack here. The four lines of error that you have put does not clarify where exactly the error is occurring. I reckon the procedure `CHECKPASSWORDUSED` is calling another procedure `CHECK_PASSWORD_USED` which does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered the answer!

Since this is my first time using Oracle I was unaware of 'Synonyms'.  I had the dba create a synonym for the stored procedure and now I'm rocking and rolling!

For anyone interested you can read more about it here:

> http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/synonyms.php
>   http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7001.htm